# how to use date in where clause to search data from access data base in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i want to search data from my data base using date in where clause.
But i am getting an error while executing the code.
I am trying this code.

```
Sub comboboxSELECTED()
    Dim a As Date
    Form1.ComboBox1.Text = a

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Mdm.accdb"
    con.Open()

    Dim q As String = "select * from Rice Where DateReceived =" & Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedText
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, con)

    Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While Reader.Read

        Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(Reader(0))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(1))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(2))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(3))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(4))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(5))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(6))
        Form1.ListView1.Items(Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Reader(7))
        Form1.DateTimePicker1.Text = Reader("DateReceived")
        Form1.TxtEnrolment.Text = Reader("Enrolment")

        Form1.TxtReceived.Text = Reader("QtyReceived")
        Form1.TxtTotal.Text = Reader("TotalQuantity")
        Form1.TxtUtilised.Text = Reader("QtyUtilised")
        Form1.TxtBalance.Text = Reader("Balance")

    End While
    Reader.Close()

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. You are going to need to edit your question to include the details of the error/exception that you are receiving when running the above code. Please post as properly formatted text. Thanks!

Comment: First, that is not the right way to build a SQL query.  Always use SQL Parameters.  One problem is that you are passing text rather than a date. Second you should really use explicit form instances.  You should also put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.  Next, a DataGridView would be much easier to use.  No need to convert to and from String and it will populate itself using a DataSource.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing that section of code to this:

```
String q = "select * from Rice Where DateReceived = @datercvd"; 
OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, con);
OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@datercvd", OleDbType.DBDate);
objectdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedText); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);
```

It does a match on the date, converts from a string, and takes care of SQL injection isues.

Comment: This code wont compile, also the OP question is `vb.net` ***not*** `c#`... You are combining both languages...

Comment: Yeah...that was pretty bad

Answer (score 0):

The VB.net code...

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSelected()
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Mdm.accdb"
            Dim q As String = "Select * from Rice Where DateReceived =@DateReceived"
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateReceived", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedText)
                con.Open()
                Using Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    While Reader.Read
                        'Your code
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```